# how to handle single quote in $.ajax POST (JQuery)?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, json

```
.ajax({

type: 'POST',

url: '..serverices/ajaxserver.asmx',

data: 'lname='+ $('#lastname').val()

}); return false;
```

if #lastname has a single quote, it throws an error. How to handle it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chetan is right on—jQuery handles that for you. But, it's worth mentioning the JavaScript `escape()` function, which is pretty simple:

```
>>> "O'Malley"
"O'Malley"
>>> escape("O'Malley")
"O%27Malley"
```

Comment: this is 2 years old - but encodeURIComponent DOES NOT WORK! it escapes double quotes and not single quotes , escape() does work

Answer (score 3):

Don't built the query string yourself when jQuery can do it for you

```
data: {"lname" : $('#lastname').val()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pair format like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '..serverices/ajaxserver.asmx',
  data: { "lname" : $('#lastname').val() }
});
```